# Application Preferences setting bundle for username and password in phonegap(iphone)

Tags: cordova

I am using phonegap framework for ios development using Jquery+html+css.

I need to save my username and password in iphone default setting, for one time login.

I have implemented  (window.plugins.
applicationPreferences.set) and  (window.plugins.applicationPreferences.get) in my js file, but phonegap plugins not supporting (windows,plugins) instead of , I directely call the protocol (applicationPreferences.prototype.set) and (applicationPreferences.prototype.get).

When i call protocol method its working(alert message) but, i need to access (window.plugins.applicationPreferences.set).
I'm still having issues with this plugin.

I have tried a few things but it doesn't seem to work.
It would be really helpful if somebody could suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Anyone having luck using Application Preferences plugin for phonegap bundle setting.

Please guide me .Thanks in advance.